# issue to sum fields

Tags: javascript

This is a basic html/javascript code, but I am having issues getting the sum of all fields.
(*The are 50 fields in the original project, but now I just leave 5*)

If the field is blank, it just has to ignore it, and add only those with filled fields.

HTML code:

```
value1:<input type="text" id="total_1" ><br>
value2:<input type="text" id="total_2" ><br>
value3:<input type="text" id="total_3" ><br>
value4:<input type="text" id="total_4" ><br>
value5:<input type="text" id="total_5" ><br>
total:<input type="text" id="totalresult" >
<button type="button" onclick="getTotal(); return false;">Get total</button>
```

Javascript:

```
function getTotal() {
var sum;
for (i = 1; i <=5 ; i++) {
    var total = document.getElementById('total_' + i.toString()).value;
    if (total != '') {
        sum = parseFloat(total) + sum;
        document.getElementById('totalresult').value = sum;
    }

  }

}
```

I don't know why my code is isn't working.

Here is my [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xvrtM/3/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to do two things. 1, initialize sum to zero. 2, check the input values for not being a number.

```
function getTotal() {
    var sum = 0;
    for (i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {
        var total = document.getElementById('total_' + i).value;
        if (!isNaN(parseFloat(total))) sum = parseFloat(total) + sum;
        document.getElementById('totalresult').value = sum;
    }
}
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/xvrtM/12/)**

Answer (score 3):

The first time your code runs, sum will be undefined.

Initialize

```
var sum = 0;
```

Also to make it work in the fiddle, you need to change

the onLoad on the left top to 'No wrap - in '

Comment: thanks for replying @ParthikGosar tried that, but the issue still is there

Answer (score 1):

I don't know why your fiddle can't figure out to make `getTotal` a global. But your main problem is that sum is undefined as start. This will result in `NaN` (Not a Number) :

```
var sum;

sum = 1 + sum; // NaN
```

....

```
sum = 1 + undefined; // NaN

sum = 1 + NaN; // NaN
```

[Demo at jsbin.com](http://jsbin.com/abasuz/1/edit)

You should set sum equal zero at first:

```
var sum = 0;
for ( ... ) { ...
```

[Working demo as adrianp pointed out: `It would probably be more clear if you uploaded the working code to jsbin.`](http://jsbin.com/abasuz/2/edit)

Comment: It would probably be more clear if you uploaded the working code to jsbin.

Answer (score 1):

You haven't defined sum variable so javascript takes that as NaN, which means Not a Number. You need to initilaize it to set it right.

```
  function getTotal() {
            var sum = 0;
    for (i = 1; i <=5 ; i++) {
    var total = document.getElementById('total_' + i.toString()).value;
if(isNaN(total) || total.indexOf(' ') == 1) {
    alert("Please type a number");
    document.getElementById("totalresult").value = "I cant sum alphanumerics";
    return false;
} 

if (total != '') {
    sum = parseFloat(total) + sum;
    document.getElementById('totalresult').value = sum;
}
```

}
}

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/xvrtM/19/)**

Comment: Doesn't work if you type a space or non-numeric character in a field.

Comment: @j08691 Hard to believe that OP is considering production code.

Comment: @j08691:  Thanks, I edited the code a little for alphanumerics.

Answer (score 0):

Use `IsNumeric` function to check if the input field has a valid number. See: [Validate decimal numbers in JavaScript - IsNumeric()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18082/validate-numbers-in-javascript-isnumeric)

Here is my suggestion to improve the code inside your for loop:

```
var elementValue = document.getElementById('total_' + i).value
IsNumeric(elementValue) ? elementValue : elementValue = 0;
```